# Error on sent to another address: InvalidRentPayingAccount

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

Suddenly most of my transaction start receiving: "InvalidRentPayingAccount" as a error even sent ones, how come, should i update solana packages or what?

```
                instruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
                    fromPubkey: this._signer.publicKey,
                    toPubkey: to,
                    lamports: txRequest.value.toNumber(),
                });
            }

            transaction = new SolTransaction({ recentBlockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash }).add(instruction);
        }

        const hash = await this.chainProvider.getProvider().sendTransaction(transaction, [this._signer], {
            skipPreflight: true,
        });
```

Comment: can we get more context, when did you start receiving the errors, what's your code etc...

Comment: Normal transfer function, it was working without problem for past few weeks and recently start seeing this error:

```
instruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
  fromPubkey: this._signer.publicKey,
  toPubkey: to,
  lamports: txRequest.value.toNumber(),
                });
            }

            transaction = new SolTransaction({ recentBlockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash }).add(instruction);
        }

        const hash = await this.chainProvider.getProvider().sendTransaction(transaction, [this._signer], {
            skipPreflight: true,
        });

```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the account you are transferring *from* is not rent-exempt, and the amount that would be left after the transfer would put it below the [rent-exemption minimum](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#rent-exemption).

You may have noticed this happen all of a sudden because all token accounts were required to meet the rent exemption minimum [recently](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/24049).